# Vue JS Load dynamic Data issue with Modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

This is my table Data

```
 <tr v-for="company, index in companies.data" :key="index.id">
                <td>{{ company.first_name }} {{ company.last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ company.license_no }}</td>
                <td>{{ company.car_registration }}</td>
                <td>
                <button id="show-modal"  @click="modalOpen(0)" class="view-button">Call</button>
                 <modal v-model="compnay" v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
                        <h3 slot="header" style="margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">{{company.first_name}} {{ company.last_name }}</h3>
                        <h3 slot="body">Car Registration No: {{company.car_registration}}</h3>                        
                    </modal>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

I have passed the dynamic data to modal slots
it is showing the same every time i click on different item
In my API i have different data & also in my table is showing different data but in modal loading same data.
This is Modal Content

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">         
            </slot>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="el">
            <slot name="body">
            </slot>
            <slot name="test">
             Calling  @{{modalcompany}}

            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">

              <button class="modal-default-button view-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>
```

Modal Content

Comment: share any live demo / snippet for this ?

Comment: Sorry about that i don't have live demo,

Comment: we can't do much without knowing your modal code component.

Comment: @ChainList  Check again i have update the question

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can we have the JS part of your modal component as well? :)

Comment: Apart from the JS. To me the problem is, you generate all your modals with the same triggered variable. So all the modals are shown, but the first one in your in is apparing on the top of all of the other one. Try to put your modal off your `v-for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution from my guess to solve your problem, I hope it helps!

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="company in companies">
    <div class="company">
      {{ company.name }} - <button @click="openModal(company)"> View appointments</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <modal v-model="showModal" company="company">
    <div slot="header">{{company.name}}</div>
    <div slot="body">{{(company.appointments || []).join(', ')}}</div>
  </modal>
</div>
```

You can see the full demo here: https://codepen.io/chainlist/pen/qMjBOQ

Comment: Thanks for your help works great, Other than your i have already solved the problem changing the variable name. the problem was with my company variable. , anyways thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to here. I don't know if performances is one of your concern, but the solution presented above has a lighter DOM since we are not generating a modal per company, thus a lighter page..